# Oracle/SQL: How can I show dates and counts even when count is zero?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

So, I need to query a table and show counts per day even if that count is zero.  I tried something like the below, but it doesn't show the days that have a count of zero.  Anyone have any other ideas?  Using Oracle, BTW.  Many thanks!!

```
with the_dates as (
  select to_date('080114','MMDDYY') + level - 1 as the_date
    from dual
 connect by level <= to_date('011716', 'MMDDYY') 
                     - to_date('080114', 'MMDDYY') + 1
         )
select distinct trunc(a.the_date), count(*)
from the_dates a
left outer join TableFoo f on a.the_date = to_date(admit_date, 'MMDDYYYY')
where f.customer_num = 10
group by trunc(a.the_date)
order by trunc(a.the_date);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.  So:

```
with . . .
select trunc(a.the_date), count(f.customer_num)
from the_dates a left outer join
     TableFoo f
     on a.the_date = to_date(admit_date, 'MMDDYYYY') and
        f.customer_num = 10
group by trunc(a.the_date)
order by trunc(a.the_date);
```

Also, `select distinct` is almost never needed when using `group by` (and certainly not in this case).